# Is it possible to load Linux OS over the network on a windows 7 pc?

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, multi-boot, nas

I have seen a Windows 7 PC that dual-booted Windows 7 from the internal hard drive and Linux Centos 6.5 over the network.

Can I do the same with my PC to boot Linux over the network? I have a WD My Cloud EX2 NAS?

Comment: It's possible, but requires a lot of manual setup.  You'd need a server to provide the kernel image (via TFTP or NFS) and an optional NFS root filesystem.  On the PC you have to install a bootloader to initiate the netboot.  You could either use a local rootfs or use NFS or a combination.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**
Yes; It is possible and it is easy.

Just take a look at [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html). (I'm related to Serva development)

Comment: This looks real interesting +1 for the info as it seems like it will actually be real beneficial to future projects of mine.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
No, not with just a NAS drive.

Booting over the network requires a server that will either respond to PXE requests, or is configured to deliver a TFTP boot image to clients.  Most consumer-grade NAS devices do not support this kind of setup.

To accomplish this, you would need a server on your network with a proper configuration, or a high-end commercial grade NAS appliance.  There is a significant amount of work to accomplish this and is beyond the scope of the question you asked.